# call_command not working, did everything like the tutorial

Tags: python, django

So just like the title suggest. i followed the instrcutions.
this is the code.

the command doesnt work not from the command line either. zero idea why

```
import time
from django.db import connections
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
from core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
"""django command to pause execution is available"""

 def handle(self, *args, **options):
    self.std.write('waiting for database...')
    db_conn = None
    while not db_conn:
        try:
            db_conn = connections[default]
        except:
            self.std.out('Database unavailable, wait 1 sec')
            time.sleep(1)


    self.std.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Database available'))
```

in the call is in a unit test just a line with `command_call('wait_for_db')` (the name of the file ofcourse)

this is the [test unit](https://github.com/therealgenish/recipe-app-api/blob/master/app/core/tests/test_commands.py) and this is the [wait for db command](https://github.com/therealgenish/recipe-app-api/blob/master/app/core/management.py/commands/wait_for_db.py)

thnkx yall

Comment: Shouldn't you indent the function handle? Otherwise its not part of the class.

Comment: @ArielA it's indented in the code, edited it. thankx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Management commands for your app should be in a directory named `<app>/management/commands/`. You have named the management directory "management.py", it should be "management"